# Is there a way to get sqlx to print the SQL code that it generates (after binding parameters)?

Tags: rust-sqlx

I have a `String` called `main_sql` and a `Vec<String>` called `main_params`.

`main_sql` looks something like: `INSERT INTO "foo" ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4") VALUES (?, ?, NULL, ?)`

`main_params` looks like `["some string", "another string", "yet another string"]`

I then call the following code to execute the insert statement against my database:

```
    use sqlx::{
        ...
        query as sqlx_query, ...
    };

    ...

    let mut main_query = sqlx_query(&main_sql);
    for param in &main_params {
        main_query = main_query.bind(param);
    }
    let main_result = main_query.execute(pool).await;
    
    ...
```

This all works fine as far as inserting the data to the database goes. However I would like to be able to print out the literal query that is executed, including the bound parameters. (The main use case is that I would like to have the literal insert statements saved in a file so that I can easily repopulate the db afterwards.) So, in the above example, that means I would like to be able to print out:

`INSERT INTO "foo" ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4") VALUES ('some string', 'another string', NULL, 'yet another string')`

One might think that the [sqlx::query::Query::sql](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/trait.Execute.html#tymethod.sql) method would do the trick. However that does not print the string with bound variables, but still includes the `?` in the output. That is, in the above example, this will just print:

`INSERT INTO "foo" ("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4") VALUES (?, ?, NULL, ?)`

Is there a way to print out generated SQL *including* bound variables using `sqlx`?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you work it out? I thought that enabling `log_statements()` in the `PgOptions` was the solution, but [that's not working for me](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/discussions/3127).

Comment: Hi @NickK9 we ended up doing it ourselves. See the function [interpolate_sql()](https://github.com/ontodev/sqlrest.rs/blob/main/src/lib.rs#L2933), which is a part of [sqlrest.rs](https://github.com/ontodev/sqlrest.rs). You can see an example of how to use it in the README for the repo.